# Java ScheduledExecutorService scheduleWithFixedDelay stops some threads from refreshing after some time

Tags: java

I have an array of 32 cache objects and I am refreshing each of the cache periodically after every 20 seconds. Attached code snippet below.

I am observing that few caches stops refreshing after some refresh cycles and there is no exception printed in the logs. Note that application is not crashing, but some caches are not getting refreshed.

```
public class CacheManager
{

    private static class CacheRefresher extends Thread
    {
        Cache cache; 

        public CacheRefresher(Cache cache)
        {
            this(cache);
        }

        @Override
        public final void run()
        {

                try {
                    LOG.info("cache is getting refreshed for " + cache.type);
                    cache.refreshCache();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    String subject = "Cache refresh failed in BMW";
                    LOG.log(Level.WARN, subject + ". Exception thrown:", e);

                }
        }       
    }

    public void refreshCaches(List<cache> caches)
    {
        ThreadFactory ourThreadFactory =
                new NamedThreadFactory("CacheHandler", true);

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduleService =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(32, ourThreadFactory);
        initialDelay = 60;
        for (Cache cache : caches) {  
            service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CacheRefresher(cache), initialDelay, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            initialDelay += 2;
            cacheContainers.add(cache);
        }
    }
}
```

After taking a thread dump I found that thread that stops refreshes is in TIMED_WAITING state.

```
"CacheHandler-19" daemon prio=5 Id=75 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6b5fe7dc
        at java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@6b5fe7dc
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
        at java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
```

Comment: Why did you make `CacheRefresher` extend `Thread`? It should be sufficient to just implement `Runnable` interface as it is not actually used as thread. The `start()` method is never called.

If some of your cache refreshes stop and are not triggered after the specified delay, the most likely explanation is, that the `refreshCache()` method never returned. Have you tried adding an additional log message after the call to `cache.refreshCache()`? There might be some kind of deadlock - but it 's hard to tell without knowing the users of the cache and what is done in order to refresh the cache.

Comment: @JochenReinhardt After taking a thread dump I found that thread that stops refreshes is in TIMED_WAITING state, rest of the threads remain in WAITING state. Any pointers from this input?

Comment: This looks like normal operation. Your code is not involved in the thread dump. It's just the scheduler waiting for the next delay to expire. The difference in state results from a difference in the leader thread. Not sure what that means, though.   Have you tried adding an additional log statement when a cache refresh is finished? What threads are shown for these log messages? Is there some type of cache that faces the issues more frequently than others?

Comment: BTW: You have 32 caches and the minimum of 32 threads in your thread pool. This does not seem to make much sense to me. You'll only have two threads running in parallel if a refresh takes more time than the initial delay difference of tow seconds. You might be wasting quite a lot of resources here.

Comment: makes sense, yes I added logs but it didn't help.

Comment: @JochenReinhardt Is it possible that a thread is exceeding max heap limit and error is getting thrown but since I am not catching error I am not observing it? But not sure if outofmemoryerror is thrown by one thread then will the entire application stop or only a thread will get impacted? Any comment on this?

Comment: There is no heap limit per thread. If you were facing heap memory / garbage collector issues, then all threads would be affected.
What about the logs? Do you see the last completed log message for the caches that stopped refreshing? Or is the last message actually a `start refresh` message?